# Шкурка, корица от итальянского «Scorza»?

Tags: этимология

Являются ли «шкурка» и «корица» этимологическими родственниками итальянского слова «Scorza»?

Comment: Не базовое слово, а уменьшительное. Почему?

Comment: ибо так созвучнее

Comment: Произойти Шкурка могла только от русской Шкуры, а не итальянской.

Comment: Если ставлю « - » вопросу / ответу, значит хочу, чтобы участник (форума) как то изменил их в лучшую сторону или изменился сам. Как «обминусованный» вдоль и поперек участник может что либо улучшить, если суть претензии никоим образом не сформулирована? Неужели это так сложно, взять да и сопроводить свою оценку в виде « - » буквально парой напутственных слов?

Comment: Поставил минус, потому что вопрос похож на необдуманный. Взять слово, посмотреть, как оно будет выглядеть в других языках, найди поверхностное сходство и сделать выводы о родстве — ложный путь, и, не применяя элементарных знаний о русской грамматике, нельзя прийти к правильным выводам.

Answer (score 1):

Все три слова восходят к праиндоевропейскому корню **(s)ker-* «резать». *Шкура*, изначально звучало как *скора*, и *кора* обозначали «нечто срезанное», *корица* — это буквально «корка», «корочка».